# JFrame: Easy key binds?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

First off, I am new to programming and I am working on a small application where I want key binds for the user to be able to press.  Currently, I am using the Virtual Key which means you have to press *ALT+KEY* but I'd rather it just be that you have to press *KEYPRESS*. Code I have for the *KeyListener*.

My button current keybind:

```
commandsButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

My button listener:

```
commandsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            runCommand();
      }});
```

I'd rather be able to press just "*A*" and not "*ALT+A*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could use the [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API, for example...

```
InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap am = getActionMap();

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "Press.A");
am.put("Press.A", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        gameConsole.append("\n\nCommands: \n ==========");
        commands();
    }
});
```

Now the great thing about this is, you can reuse the `Action`...

For example...

```
public class ConsoleAction extends AbstractAction {

    public ConsoleAction() {
        putValue(NAME, "Text of button");
        putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0));
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_A);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        gameConsole.append("\n\nCommands: \n ==========");
        commands();
    }
}
```

And then...

```
ConsoleAction consoleAction = new ConsoleAction();
JButton consoleButton = new JButton(consoleAction);
//...
am.put(consoleAction);
```

Comment: I had very similar code to this! I am so glad you were able to respond quickly! I will green check ASAP! Thanks!